# DNS Lookup Slow On LAN After Upgrade to 18.04 LTS

Tags: networking, dns, 18.04

spent a bunch of time poking around the site for an answer to this issue. Namely when I `ping 8.8.8.8` the action starts immediately but when I `ping www.google.com` there is about 10 seconds lag where the DNS doesn't seem to resolve to the correct IP address. Keep in mind that I am a relative linux noob so I tried not to make any radical changes (and yes, maybe upgrading to 18.04 was a little ambitious).

The results of `ifconfig` are:

```
enp0s31f6: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 1c:1b:0d:0f:a0:5d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 16  memory 0xda100000-da120000  

enp5s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.7.62  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.7.255
        inet6 fe80::2cae:25b:5a44:1a8c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 1c:1b:0d:0f:a0:5b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 92706  bytes 66911507 (66.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 65071  bytes 11095750 (11.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 18  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1213082  bytes 79847277 (79.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1213082  bytes 79847277 (79.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

When I `dhclient -v enp0s31f6` there is a DHCPDISCOVER process that does not resolve. When I `dhclient -v enp5s0` I get immediate an immediate answer.

As asked for, results for `nslookup` below:

```
nslookup www.google.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 172.217.7.228
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 2607:f8b0:4004:80f::2004

nslookup www.google.com 8.8.8.8
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 172.217.3.36
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 2607:f8b0:4006:81b::2004
```

Other requests:

```
nmcli device show enp5s0 | grep IP4.DNS
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
```

Happy to do the work necessary to get this resolved, just need some direction as to where the problem lies.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Does it successfully resolve www.google.com when 10 seconds has passed or does it fail?

Comment: What is the result of `nslookup www.google.com` and what is the result of `nslookup www.google.com 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: Also, what is the output of `nmcli device show enp5s0 | grep IP4.DNS`?

Comment: I've added the requested information. Hope this helps, and thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 1):

Your computer is connected to the subnet *192.168.7.62/24* (netmask 255.255.255.0) and configured to use *192.168.1.1* as DNS server. Unless you have multiple VLANs in you network with routing in between this could be the issue.

Since you clearly have access to Googles Public DNS (8.8.8.8) you should try using that as your DNS server instead.

*Note! You might have to restart your computer for the changes to take effect (or restart networking).*

Go into the Network Settings and Edit your connection profile:
[image: Edit profile]

Then turn off **Automatic** DNS so your DHCP server doesn't hand out the (perhaps) faulty DNS server again, and enter **8.8.8.8** manually:
[image]